# Python CSV double quotes between array

Tags: python, csv

I am working on CSV files. How can I add double quotes between array?

```
    marketplaces = ['amazon', 'ebay', 'alibaba', 'walmart']
        with open('example.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        # Writing data to a file
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            writer.writerow(marketplaces)
```

Print

```
"amazon","ebay","alibaba","walmart"
```

I want like this

```
"amazon,ebay,alibaba,walmart"
```

Comment: `writer.writerow(','.join(marketplaces))`

Comment: The output you're asking for is not a valid CSV file that puts each word of the array in a different cell. The library is correct to refuse to give it to you when you give it input that places those words in separate list entries. (Compare to RJ's comment, where the code creates a single list entry with all four words).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually  it is valid for woocommerce tags. The following code is working

Comment: @Melisa, sure, but it's putting all the words together (with commas between them) in _one_ cell, it's not putting each word in a single cell. The qualifiers in my sentence ("not a valid CSV file **that puts each word of the array in a different cell**") were there for a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Done!

```
marketplaces = ['amazon', 'ebay', 'alibaba', 'walmart']
    with open('example.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            # Writing data to a file
                f.write('"')
                for marketplace in marketplaces:
                    if marketplace != marketplaces[len(marketplaces)-1]:
                        f.write(marketplace + ",")
                    else:
                        f.write(marketplaces)
                f.write('"\n')
```

Output

```
"amazon,ebay,alibaba, walmart"
```

Comment: This code creates a `csv.writer` but doesn't use it at all (it only uses `f.write()`, not `writer.writerow()`). Why create a `writer` if you aren't going to use it?

Comment: oh sorry, that's unnecessary. i must have been missed it. csv.writer should be deleted.